# Odoo onchange not working correctly

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9

I'm inherit purchase.order.line and try change value in field. For product_qty I can change value but for price_unit I can't change value.

My custom .py file:

```
class PurchaseOrderLine(models.Model):

_inherit = 'purchase.order.line'


@api.onchange('product_id')
def my_fucn(self):
    for rec in self:
        rec.product_qty = 10  #WORKING
        rec.price_unit = 1    #NOT WORKING
```

Maybe is problem because in original purcahase.py odoo file also have @api.onchange('product_id').

Any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't predict which onchange method will be triggered first or last, but the original onchange method for `product_id` changes in `purchase.order.line` is setting the `price_unit` field, but not the `product_qty` field.

So it seems your method is called before the other one, because `price_unit` is overwritten. You can check that by debugging both methods.

What to do now? I would prefer the extension of the original method:

```py
@api.onchange('product_id')
def the_original_method(self):
    res = super(PurchaseOrderLine, self).the_original_method()
    # your logic here
    return res
```

In your case a `product_qty` change will trigger another onchange event. Always have in mind, that field changes can trigger onchange events and field recomputations.

Try to extend both methods:

```py
@api.onchange('product_id')
def onchange_product_id(self):
    res = super(PurchaseOrderLine, self).onchange_product_id()
    # your logic here
    for rec in self:
        rec.product_qty = 10  # will trigger _onchange_quantity() on return

    return res

@api.onchange('product_qty', 'product_uom')
def _onchange_quantity(self):
    res = super(PurchaseOrderLine, self)._onchange_quantity()
    # your logic here
    for rec in self:
        rec.price_unit = 1.0

    return res
```

Comment: Tnx for help, I'm use your exampke I'm replace the_original_method with odoo default  def onchange_product_id  but again not working.  In console onchange('product_id') first triggered myfunction then odoo onchange_product_id

Comment: Okay, that's a bit complicated for your case, because the change on `product_qty` is triggering `_onchange_quantity()` which is changing `price_unit`. So try to extend both methods. `onchange_product_id()` with a `product_qty` change and `_onchange_quantity()` with the `price_unit` change.

Comment: sorry but I don't know how extedend bot method. Please put all code in your answer. Tnx!

Comment: It's the same only for another method. But yes i will edit it in.