# odoo 11 @api.onchange() not working on price_unit field in purchase.order.line

Tags: python, odoo, onchange, odoo-11

odoo 11 onchange not working on price_unit in purchase.order.line, while it is working on the discount field.

Below is my code which I copied from [Odoo onchange not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51724911/odoo-onchange-not-working-correctly) and then modified:

```
@api.onchange('product_id')
def onchange_product_id(self):
    res = super(PurchaseOrderLine, self).onchange_product_id()
    # your logic here
    for rec in self:
        rec.price_unit = rec.product_id.list_price  

        return res

@api.onchange('price_unit')
def _onchange_price_unit(self):
    res = super(PurchaseOrderLine, self)._onchange_price_unit()
    # your logic here
    for rec in self:
        rec.discount = rec.product_id.puchase_price_discount
        return res
```

Comment: Try to extend `_onchange_quantity()` as in my answer you've mentioned and set `price_unit` there.

Comment: copied exact code now given on the link, still not working :(

Comment: Okay, found the issue, I have wrongly indented return in both the functions

Comment: What was the final solution? Just post it as your answer.

Comment: Just posted, thanks for guiding me through

Answer (score 0):

**Solution that worked:**

```
class PurchaseOrderLine(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'purchase.order.line'
    _description = "Purchase Order Line"


    @api.onchange('product_id')
    def onchange_product_id(self):

        res = super(PurchaseOrderLine,self).onchange_product_id()

        for rec in self:
            self.price_unit = 10

        return res
```